# Create a div before another

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-validation-engine

I have a script from a JQuery Validation Engine. I want to set the prompt div before another div.

```
if($('#'+methods._getClassName(field.attr("id"))+'_msddHolder').length ){
var prompt = $('<div>');
$('#'+methods._getClassName(field.attr("id"))+'_msddHolder').before(prompt);
prompt.addClass(methods._getClassName(field.attr("id")) + "formError");
// add a class name to identify the parent form of the prompt
prompt.addClass("parentForm"+methods._getClassName(field.closest('form, .validationEngineContainer').attr("id")));
prompt.addClass("formError");
```

If I do it like this it won't work, if i manually set this:

```
$('#'+methods._getClassName(field.attr("id"))+'_msddHolder').before('<div>TEST</div>');
```

Then it works. Why?

Comment: What exactly "won't work"? If you are not specific about your problem we have to guess, which has less chances to be of any help to you.

Comment: The best thing you can do is create a http://www.jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apply class after your before method. The class won't apply then on your element. Have you tried :

```
var prompt = $('<div><h4>I am a test</h4></div>');
$('#'+methods._getClassName(field.attr("id"))+'_msddHolder').before(prompt);
```

Just to see if you have an element insered ?

Comment: Why should `prompt.addClass` not work? It does not matter whether an element is in the tree or not.

Answer (score 0):

prompt isn't a pointer to your DOM element that you appended using before(), it is just a variable that contains an empty div, you need to apply its class before appending it to your document.

```
var prompt = $('<div>');
prompt.addClass("formError");
$('#'+methods._getClassName(field.attr("id"))+'_msddHolder').before(prompt);
```

Comment: What do you think jQuery is doing with the DOM element when it is inserted? Why would `prompt` not point to the inserted element anymore?

Comment: You are all over this question aren't you, maybe try answering it? To answer your question, jQuery is adding a class to the div that is stored in the prompt var, and not to the div that was appended to the document using before().

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to prevent incorrect answers. And I will answer the question once I have the information I need. So far I haven't. The element that `prompt` refers to is the same as the one that is inserted. jQuery does not create a copy (unless multiple elements are selected). Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/EJjdY/.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var prompt = $('<div>').text('test');
```